# How to unify appearance of android application

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock

I develop an android application and I use ActionBarSherlock library. When I run my application on emulator (Android 4.1) then my application looks great.

I tried to run my application on a physical device (HTC Desire, Android 2.2.2) but it does not look the same. It is possible to  unification of appearance  between different android versions?

Here is a screenshot: http://files.1qa.pl/screen.jpg

I would like to unify appearance of view content (widgets like TextEdit, Spinner etc). The top bar looks fine.

Comment: Please upload screenshots somewhere, link to them from your question, then explain **completely and precisely** what aspects of "does not look the same" you are concerned about.

Comment: To do that you need to follow guidelines and do everything properly.